# how do i fix PyQt6 import problem on macos?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

I'm trying to run my Python3 .pyw script on MacOS which used to run okay, but now gets error.

(Could not find solution by Googling)

THE CODE IN MY .pyw FILE ...

```
import os
import signal

from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys
from include.BaseDialog import BaseDialog

if __name__ == '__main__':
    qapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    qapp.setWindowIcon(QIcon(f'{sys.path[0]}/include/Icon.png'))


    styleSheet = """
            
        """
    qapp.setStyleSheet(styleSheet)
    app = BaseDialog()
    qapp.aboutToQuit.connect(app.close_program)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, app.close_program)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, app.close_program)
    sys.exit(qapp.exec())
```

THE ERROR ...

```
> root@Dougs-MacBook-2023 softwarehubgui # Python3 SoftwareHubGUI.pyw 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/me/PRIMARY/WORK/MOJO/Software/softwarehubgui/SoftwareHubGUI.pyw",
> line 4, in <module>
>     from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt6/QtGui.abi3.so,
> 0x0002): Symbol not found:
> __ZN13QRasterWindow11resizeEventEP12QResizeEvent
> 
>   Referenced from: <C8D7E625-2A13-3C34-9DFF-B6656A6F86E7>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt6/QtGui.abi3.so
> Expected in:     <FC67C721-05AD-33BB-A2A8-F70FC3403D7A>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt6/Qt6/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/A/QtGui
```

Comment: How did you install PyQt6, exactly?

Comment: Are you using a venv? Are you running the script from the IDE or from a terminal?

Comment: Tim: pip3 install PyQt6

Comment: musicamante: I've tried IDE (doubleclick app.vyw) and terminal -- both fail, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that PyQt6 is no longer compatible with my python 3.11 so pip install PyQt6 caused the error.

Bard chat told me the compatible version... to wit...

SOLUTION...
pip install pyqt6==6.6.0